# gcc does not find files that are on the search path

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

I'm using software on Linux Ubuntu 14.04 64bit that uses gcc.  I get errors about files or programs not being found like these:

```
cc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

or

```
fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
```

However, when I do

```
gcc -print-search-dirs
```

I get many paths, and `cc1` is on the first path in that list (`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/`).   I do not understand this.

Then I created a link to cc1 as follows (in /usr/bin):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1 cc1
```

Now the first error disappears, but I get the second error.  Strange again, because I have this file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h` which is again on the gcc search path.`

I'm not an expert in gcc at all, but this makes no sense to me.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This looks like a botched installation of the compiler toolchain. I suggest reinstalling the toolchain.

Comment: I tried to do that twice so far.  Here's what I did last: ``sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc`` then ``sudo apt-get remove gcc`` and then ``sudo apt-get install gcc g++ gcc-multilib g++-multilib libstdc++6:i386 build-essential``.  This does not solve the problems.

Comment: problem with path or permissions. in case of executables, an additonal problem can be that executables are for wrong architecture.

Comment: I can ask my software to use clang, and then it works fine. So it has to be linked to my gcc setup?